# Как добавить несколько календарей jq

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма,с инпутом для даты, которая имеет несколько одинаковых строк(т.е несколько интпутов для даты).
Есть такой скрипт

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    inline: true,
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true
});


jQuery(function ($) {
    $.datepicker.regional['ru'] = {
        closeText: 'Закрыть',
        prevText: '&#x3c;Пред',
        nextText: 'След&#x3e;',
        currentText: 'Сегодня',
        monthNames: ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь',
        'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь',
        'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'],
        dayNames: ['воскресенье', 'понедельник', 'вторник', 'среда', 'четверг', 'пятница', 'суббота'],
        dayNamesShort: ['вск', 'пнд', 'втр', 'срд', 'чтв', 'птн', 'сбт'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Вс', 'Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб'],
        weekHeader: 'Нед',
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''
    };
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['ru']);
});
$(function () {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker($.extend({
            inline: true,
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
        },
         $.datepicker.regional['ru']
       ));
    });
```

Если бы строка была 1 было бы все гуд. Но строк несколько. Поэтому календарь появляется только в 1 инпуте(скрипт id добавляет).
Вопрос как сделать чтоб календарь открывался во всех интпутах(видимо нужно задавать datepicker как класс, а не id). В JS не разбираюсь помогите.

Answer (score 2):

Всё верно, идентификатор в коде документа должен быть в единственном экземпляре, иными словами, встречаться только один раз. Это правила часто игнорируют начинающие разработчики и не только начинающие, и видимо `datepicker` работает по этому правилу.

В вашем случае замените id `datepicker` к примеру на такой же класс `datepicker`, тогда всё должно отработать.